# What is this very small bug with two antennae and 6 legs?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, pennsylvania

In my bathroom, I keep finding these very small bugs. They have 6 legs from what I can tell, two antennae, and they look grey in color (although the picture makes them look more of a tan):

[image: bug on white background]

They are very small, smaller than a sugar ant even. What are these?
I'm in south east Pennsylvania,  I would ideally like to know if they are destructive. From my research, they might be a springtail but I'm not positive.

Comment: Where in the world are you? It is very hard to ID without an approx location and better photos. You may have better luck asking for this to be moved to the Biology SE.

Comment: The traditional name for these is "small brown bug". Too many options to identify exactly. What are you interested in — family/genus/species or harmless/icky/dangerous?

Comment: @TimmyJim, yes much better, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Information discussed has helped me identify the little pests that I started seeing around my kitchen sink. It turns out that they are springtails. They are about 2 mm long with a streamline body, and they hop pretty fast. In addition to humidifier, I learned that infested area can be treated with cider vinegar which will help get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

springtail bug most likely. according to what i searched up they adore moisture, and them showing up in your house is an indicator of excess moisture, which is not too big an issue in your bathroom. Harmless lil guys, i guess if you see them elsewhere the only course of action to bother with is a dehumidifier.

Comment: This was (formerly) near a window that had a leak actually in my bathroom. It has since been fixed. You should have seen what the sheathing underneath looked like when we tore the wall down. From my research long ago, this was the bug I thought it was too.